# How can I merge this RegEx code

Tags: php, regex

I’ve written this regex code,

`/.[^.]*$/` -> file extension

`/\?.*/` -> removes everything ?paramternames in PHP

Current usage:

```
preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', preg_replace('/.[^.]*$/','',basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])))
```

How can I make it to a single preg_replace call, instead of these two, is there a way to merge the two RegExes into one single RegEx which does the job?

Can I posted expected output result? Yes.

http://localhost/books.php?tab=to_read

when I run this PHP code with two preg_replaces, I get **"books"**, which I use to highlight in the menu to tell the user current page and menu highlight based on the page URI.

EDIT: **There's nothing wrong with this code, it works. However, I want to merge the two regexes into one and only invoke one preg_replace.**

Comment: Can you post an example and expected output?

Comment: URI does not contain query string

Comment: what output after `preg_replace('/.[^.]*$/','',basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oftentimes you can just combine two patterns per alternation `one|two`.

In your case either the "file extension" or the query string might be absent, and they should be matched in the right order. Which is why you should optionalize both parts:

```
 preg_replace("~ (\.\w+)? (\?.*)?  $   ~x",
                    ↓       ↓      ↓    ↓
                  ".ext"  "?………"  END  readability flag
```

This ensures the `.ext` either directly precedes the query string, or spans the last characters itself. Likewise could the query string be optional, but still should match without preceding extension.

Comment: WOW! This worked. Can you explain this regex in details, thanks?

Comment: And it supports all types of extensions? Right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: question: if we remove extension... the last part is removed too... no? no because we have something like \w+ but.. we could?

Comment: No, it's constrained to just `\w+` word characters. So would work for `.php` or `.html5` etc, but not `.x/5` or `.%22`

Comment: Is there a solution for all extensions? With regard to test (\?.*)

Comment: @N000b101 Everything after a `?` query string marker is irrelevant. There it literally matches *anything* still. Only the `.ext` part depends on entirely alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Cool arrows. I need to remember those.

Comment: @Qix Kinda got in in the habit lately. They're often mapped to AltGr+U / Y / I.

Comment: Of course, I understand the (\?.*), but you said that \w+ only works for .php, .html5 etc. Is there a way to make it support all extensions, so that regardless of what extension we'll get the name out if it. Sounds weird, I am not good with RegEx.

Comment: @N000b101 Well you could go with your original `\.[^.]+` of course. (I just thought that somewhat too greedy/unspecific.)

Comment: @N000b101 Now I wouldn't call it bad. You're operating just on the REQUEST_URI here. If this was for a full IRI/URL it would likely mismatch domain names etc. Perhaps not relevant.  However it would behave just the same as your original 2×preg_replace approach.